# How to delete file using partial path name

Tags: c#, file, io

i have file which i need to delete but the the file path contains

`"Full System Backup-" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString() + ".zip"`

i tried to delete using below method but i get exception of unsupported format.

`File.Delete( drive path here \\" + locBTextBox.Text + "\\" + dbComboBox.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString() + ".zip'");`

i tried to place "*" instead of the datetime stamp but it returned a exception of illegal characters found.

Is there any solution how can i over come this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "Full System Backup-*.zip")
    .ToList().ForEach(File.Delete);
```

Comment: Is not it too aggressive to delete _all_ files which match to the search pattern instead of just one file?

Comment: @AlexD, Yes, It might be aggressive, but I just want to show how to select files using a `pattern`.